# Why can't I patch the value into the form controls in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, patch, setvalue

I've tried to patch some of the values to the from control, but it is not showing. why?
I'll share my code examples here,

### constructor

```
 constructor(

        private fromBuilder: FormBuilder

 ) {
        this.OrderNShippingForm = this.fromBuilder.group({

                   billTitle: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billName: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billCompany: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billAddress1: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billAddress2: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billCity: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billProvince: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billZIP: this.fromBuilder.control(''),
                   billCountry: this.fromBuilder.control(''),

        })

   }
```

### ngOninit

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.initializeForm()

}
```

### function to initialize

here the data is strored to localstorage after the initialization of this component.

```
public initializeForm() {

   if (localStorage.getItem('customer').length > 0 && localStorage.getItem('address').length > 0) {

           this.customer = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customer'));
           this.address = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('address'));
           this.populateData()

   }
}
```

### populate date

```
public populateData() {
     
    this.billAddress.title = this.address.title
    this.billAddress.name = this.address.name
    this.billAddress.company = this.address.company
    this.billAddress.address1 = this.address.address1
    this.billAddress.address2 = this.address.address2
    this.billAddress.city = this.address.city
    this.billAddress.province = this.address.province
    this.billAddress.zip = this.address.zip
    this.billAddress.country = this.address.country

    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billTitle').patchValue(this.address.title)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billName').patchValue(this.address.name.trim())
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCompany').patchValue(this.address.company)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billAddress1').patchValue(this.address.address1)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billAddress2').patchValue(this.address.address2)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCity').patchValue(this.address.city)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billProvince').patchValue(this.address.province)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billZIP').patchValue(this.address.zip)
    this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCountry').patchValue(this.address.country)

}
```

### the HTML of this component is

```
<form [formGroup]="OrderNShippingForm" autocomplete="off">
     <div class="card card-body col-6">
                    <h4>Billing Address</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <select name="billTitle" id="billTitle" formControlName="billTitle"
                                class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.title">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>Title</option>
                                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                                <option value="Mx">Mx</option>
                                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billName" id="billName" formControlName="billName"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billCompany" id="billCompany" formControlName="billCompany"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Company" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.company">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billAddress1" id="billAddress1" formControlName="billAddress1"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Address1" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.address1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billAddress2" id="billAddress2" formControlName="billAddress2"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Address2" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.address2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billCity" id="billCity" formControlName="billCity"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="city" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.city">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="billProvince" id="billProvince" formControlName="billProvince"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Province" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.province">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <input type="text" name="billZIP" id="billZIP" formControlName="billZIP"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="ZIP" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.zip">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <input type="text" name="billCountry" id="billCountry" formControlName="billCountry"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="billAddress.country">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <select name="billAddressType" id="billAddressType" formControlName="billAddressType"
                                class="form-control">
                                <option value="billing/default">Billing/Default Address</option>
                                <option value="shipping" >Shipping Address</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

also i've tried

```
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billTitle').setValue(this.address.title)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billName').setValue(this.address.name.trim())
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCompany').setValue(this.address.company)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billAddress1').setValue(this.address.address1)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billAddress2').setValue(this.address.address2)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCity').setValue(this.address.city)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billProvince').setValue(this.address.province)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billZIP').setValue(this.address.zip)
this.OrderNShippingForm.get('billCountry').setValue(this.address.country)
```

please help me resolve this. I've been trying for two three days. please comment if any more details are needed.

Comment: When do `customer` and `address` get placed in local storage?  Can you verify the exist before your ngOnInit?

Comment: Why don't you use `setValue` on formGroup?
I can see that you data is getting from localStorage as an Object that matches formGroup structure

Comment: why are you using both template driven forms and reactive forms at the same time ?

Comment: @munzer I need to bind these forms with some variable

Comment: @BizzyBob The local storage is populated after the ngOnInit(), but as the controls are binded with a variable it should listen to the changes in the variable right?

Comment: @Yuriy It doesn't match the address variable contain even more details